Can the derived set of a countable set be the Cantor set?
I was asked to construct a sequence on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the limit points of the sequence are the Cantor set, or simply to prove that is impossible.
Intuitively, I try to construct a countable set such that its derived set is the Cantor set for the Cantor set is closed on $\mathbb{R}$, but I have no idea on this.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

It's possible to find such a sequence. Hint: think about the endpoints of the intervals involved in constructing the Cantor set.

@TheoBendit Thank you very much! And I have another question: Is there any closed set that cannot be the derived set of a countable set?

I have a vague feeling that separability is important here.

@tys I believe so. Any subspace $A$ of a separable space like $\Bbb{R}$ will be separable too, meaning there'll be a countable dense subset $D$ of $A$. The derived set $D'$ will encompass all of $A$ except its isolated points, of which there are countably many, and we can simply include countably many isolated sequences to converge to said isolated points. All in all, a countable set will suffice.
